# OpenCL race condition with printf?

Tags: c, printf, opencl, intel, race-condition

I'm currently trying to test if I can get some basic operations (reading and writing memory) to work in an OpenCL kernel (Intel SDK). Here's a portion of the code--with some unused parameters omitted:

```
__kernel
void myfunc(__global char *buf_pw,
__global char *buf_hash)
{
    int idx = get_global_id(0); 
    int a = 1 + 1;   
    char wololol[8] = "wololol"; 
    if (idx == 0 )
    {
        buf_pw[0] = 'A';
        buf_pw[1] = 'e'; 
        buf_pw[2] = 'l';
        buf_pw[3] = 'l';
        buf_pw[4] = 'o';
        buf_pw[5] = 0;
    }
    if (idx == 0)
    {
        while(buf_pw[0] != 'A');
        printf("%c\n", buf_pw[0]);
        printf("%c\n", buf_pw[1]); 
        printf("%c\n", buf_pw[2]);
        printf("%c\n", buf_pw[3]); 
        printf("%c\n", buf_pw[4]);
        printf("%c\n", buf_pw[5]); 
        printf("%s\n", buf_pw);
        printf("%s\n", wololol);  
    }
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

Running the program multiple times can produce different results. Most of the time, it produces output that looks like:

```
A
e
l
l 
o

(null)
wololol
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

with the other case being:

```
A
e
l
l 
o

Aello
wololol
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

I expected the second case to be the correct output, but it rarely occurs. What's causing the weirdness with how writing/reading pw behaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be valid (though the while loop in your code was momentarily confusing! ;), and your expectation of the correct output is sound.

It seems there is a bug/issue with your OpenCL installation.  AMD GPU OpenCL drivers in particular have issues with printf behavior I have found.

The printf in question should *always* print "Aello", and *never* print "(null)", as you expect.

The problem is likely due to a race condition in the vendor implementation of printf().

Answer (score 0):

[Printf OpenCL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/printfFunction.html)

I would be carefull with "printf" function since it may not follow OpenCL's normal logic. The spec says about it:

> When the event that is associated with a particular kernel invocation is completed, the output of all printf() calls executed by this kernel invocation is flushed to the implementation-defined output stream. Calling clFinish on a command queue flushes all pending output by printf in previously enqueued and completed commands to the implementation-defined output stream. In the case that printf is executed from multiple work-items concurrently, there is no guarantee of ordering with respect to written data. For example, it is valid for the output of a work-item with a global id (0,0,1) to appear intermixed with the output of a work-item with a global id (0,0,4) and so on.